# Multiple HTML fields showing on separate lines when Disaply attribute is changed through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table where a field can be edited when a button is clicked. I have a fiddle setup for it: http://jsfiddle.net/r2rur/31/ The code for the button is:

```
<input type="submit" id="change" class="btn" value="Change" onclick="showEditFields();" />
```

showEditFields works as such: When I click on Change button, the button and label disappear and the input field with the "tick" image are displayed. What I need is for the "tick" to appear next to the input field instead of below it. I should note that if the input and image are displayed from the beginning (not through JS), the display is correct as shown in the fiddle too.

I tried working with the CSS and styling, removed all custom styling, changed margin/padding attributes etc, but nothing worked. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `input`s and `img`s are basically inline elements. You are showing them by turning their `display` to "block, which is causing this problem. Make them "inline".  Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/r2rur/32/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`block` elements takes up the entire available width. Simply change `display:block` to `inline-block` for `<input>` and `<img>`.

```
document.getElementById('inpAmount').style.display='inline-block';
document.getElementById('saveChange').style.display='inline-block';
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2rur/37/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply make the image and the input as 'inline-block' instead of 'block'. Checkout the jsfiddle.

```
document.getElementById('inpAmount').style.display='inline-block';
document.getElementById('saveChange').style.display='inline-block';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2rur/33/